# Curl install binary to users path from nodejs

Tags: node.js, curl, child-process

Hello fellow nerds and nerdettes,

I just started building a little app that uses an external command line interface. The app first checks if the binary is installed in the users path and if not offers to install it for them. The external cli bin is the  [digitalocean cli](https://github.com/digitalocean/doctl) and requires to curl, pipe to tar, and then move the bin into the users path. I have built the check if installed functionality and have been reading the child-process api but have been having a hard time figuring out how to console out the status of the curl command. My current incantation shows no console output. My question is this. How do i pipe the output of cURL to the console to confirm its working? How might i go about testing success then moving on?

Thanks y'all

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec

const curlScriptOSX = 'curl -L https://github.com/digitalocean/doctl/releases/download/v1.6.0/doctl-1.6.0-darwin-10.6-amd64.tar.gz | tar xz'

exec(curlScriptOSX, function(error, stdout, stderr) {

  console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
  console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);

  if(error !== null) {
    console.log('exec error: ' + error);
  }
})
```

UPDATE: i am looking at the request library as well. is it possible to

```
request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('binary.tar.gz')).then(exec(extracting)).catch(err => console.error(err))
```

i wonder... ima try this now

Answer (score 1):

Using the request library:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const os = require('os')
const request = require('request')
const url = 'https://github.com/digitalocean/doctl/releases/download/v1.6.0/doctl-1.6.0-darwin-10.6-amd64.tar.gz'
platform = os.platform()

function getInstallerFile (url) {
    console.log("Getting tar")
    // Variable to save downloading progress
    var received_bytes = 0;
    var total_bytes = 0;
    const output = fs.createWriteStream('doctl.tar.gz')

    request
        .get(url)
            .on('error', function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            })
            .on('response', function(data) {
                total_bytes = parseInt(data.headers['content-length']);
            })
            .on('data', function(chunk) {
                received_bytes += chunk.length;
                showDownloadingProgress(received_bytes, total_bytes);
            })
            .pipe(output);
};

function showDownloadingProgress(received, total) {
    var percentage = ((received * 100) / total).toFixed(2);
    process.stdout.write((platform == 'win32') ? "\033[0G": "\r");
    process.stdout.write(percentage + "% | " + received + " bytes of " + total + " bytes.");
}

getInstallerFile(url)
```